# Creating Files as System

Tags: c, windows, file-io, system, psexec

I am trying to get a program run by System(rather than a user) to write to a file, but I am having trouble. Running my program as a user, the file is generated correctly, but running the same program using `>PSExec -s myProgram.exe`, no file is generated. It seems to be otherwise running correctly and the file open function does not return NULL; is there something special I have to do to be able to write to a file as System?

I am having the same issue on both a Windows 7 64 bit machine and Windows XP 32.

Comment: Are you trying to create the file on a mapped network drive?

Comment: No, just my local hard drive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arguments:
Arguments to pass (note that file paths must be absolute paths on the target system)

Are you using absolute path to the file?

Also check the folder permissions, you are running the application in.

Comment: Using the absolute path seems to have solved the problem. Why is this necessary? Why doesn't opening the file fail if no file is being created?